# How to pull out CSS attributes from inline styles with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css, inline, beautifulsoup

I have something like this:

```
<img style="background:url(/theRealImage.jpg) no-repate 0 0; height:90px; width:92px;") src="notTheRealImage.jpg"/>
```

I am using beautifulsoup to parse the html. Is there away to pull out the "url" in the "background" css attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got a couple options- quick and dirty or the Right Way. The quick and dirty way (which will break easily if the markup is changed) looks like

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><img style="background:url(/theRealImage.jpg) no-repate 0 0; height:90px; width:92px;") src="notTheRealImage.jpg"/></body></html>')
>>> style = soup.find('img')['style']
>>> urls = re.findall('url\((.*?)\)', style)
>>> urls
[u'/theRealImage.jpg']
```

Obviously, you'll have to play with that to get it to work with multiple `img` tags.

The Right Way, since I'd feel awful suggesting someone use regex on a CSS string :), uses a CSS parser. [cssutils](http://cthedot.de/cssutils/), a library I just found on Google and available on PyPi, looks like it might do the job.

Comment: I included the awful regex method because I realize a ton of scraping jobs are one-offs, but if this code is going to live for more than a day it should use something better, like a CSS parser. The above example is, again, very breakable.