# how I can get all images if i'm using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

How I can a image if code like this:

```
<div class="galery-images">
<div class="galery-images-slide" style="width: 760px;">
<div class="galery-item galery-item-selected" style="background-image: url(/images/photo/1/20130206/30323/136666697057736800.jpg);"></div>
```

I want to get 136666697057736800.jpg
I wrote:

```
 images = soup.select("div.galery-item")
```

And i get a list:

```
[<div class="galery-item galery-item-selected" style="background-image: url(/images/photo/1/20130206/30323/136666697057736800.jpg);"></div>, 
<div class="galery-item" style="background-image: url(/images/photo/1/20130206/30323/136013892671126300.jpg);" ></div>, 
<div class="galery-item" style="background-image: url(/images/photo/1/20130206/30323/136666699218876700.jpg);"></div>]
```

I dont understand: how I can get all images?

Comment: You want to download the images?

Comment: yes. how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Use regex or a css parser to extract the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271365/how-to-pull-out-css-attributes-from-inline-styles-with-beautifulsoup), concatenate the host to the beginning of the URL, finally download the image like this.

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", "google.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, you should use a regex:

```
urls = []

for ele in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'galery-images-slide'}):
    pattern = re.compile('.*background-image:\s*url\((.*)\);')
    match = pattern.match(ele.div['style'])
    if match:
        urls.append(match.group(1))
```

This works by finding all the `divs` belonging to the parent div (which has the class: 'galery-images-slide'). Then, you can parse the child `divs` to find any that contain the style (which itself contains the background-url) using a regex.

So, from your above example, this will output:

```
[u'/images/photo/1/20130206/30323/136666697057736800.jpg']
```

**Now, to download the specified image, you append the site name in front of the url, and you should be able to download it.**

NOTE:

This requires the regex module (`re`) in Python in addition to `BeautifulSoup`.
And, the regex I used is quite naive. But, you can adjust this as required to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you. it's good solution, but not work. I get only one match. But I want all images from nested <div class="galery-images-slide">

Comment: @Olga, you can adapt my solution for x number of images.