# How to parse a batch webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, parsing

I want to batch export a list of flashcard sets/decks from quizlet. Rather than manually clicking on the menu, export, tick 'include pictures', copy, paste into new blank text file, save.... it would be easier to write a script to do this.

How can I do this? Can someone help give me head start (and I can do the rest, etc).

Javascript? JQuery? Python?

Need to parse a text file of URLs (the direct links to each deck).
eg.
https://quizlet.com/215441327/f1-u1a-making-friends-flash-cards/
https://quizlet.com/218503855/f1-u1b-making-friends-flash-cards/
and export.

UPDATE: Is there a way to fire the onclick for that "MORE" button (ellipsis dots), and fire click the "EXPORT"?
Then fire click the checkbox "INCLUDE PICTURES". Then grab the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

My preference is python. for starting point see the code below. I am using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package. See example below as a starting point.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://quizlet.com/215441327/f1-u1a-making-friends-flash-cards/"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html5lib")
```

To get the english words

```
for en in soup.select(".TermText.notranslate.lang-en"):
    print(en.text.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
enjoy
cheerful
everyone
sporty
sometimes
practise
practice
friend
favourite
help
```

for the other languages

```
for ch in soup.select(".TermText.notranslate.lang-zh-TW"):
    print(ch.text.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
請享用
高興的
每個人
運動型的
有時
練習
練習
朋友
最喜歡的
幫助
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Is there a way to fire the onclick for that "MORE" button (ellipsis dots), and fire click the "EXPORT"?
Then fire click the checkbox "INCLUDE PICTURES". Then grab the textarea?

Comment: @AndWan see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271365/how-to-pull-out-css-attributes-from-inline-styles-with-beautifulsoup you can directly extract the image

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium python library to interact with the webpage also:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
chromedriver = "C:\Users\pappuj\Downloads\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url='http://www.zoover.nl/cyprus'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
```